# Batch tool to automaticly crop images?

Tags: image, ocr, jpeg

I have bulk of images (1000+); each image consists of several pictures as a result of scanning several pictures to single image (JPG)
I am looking for a Batch tool that will be able to automatically crop and save the images as separated files
Is it possible? Any such tool?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of each crop and positions are the same, you can easily write processing steps using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). Then, using some script language you can process whatever number of images you want.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, the size of each crop and positions are the not the same, they are result of putting several images in scanner and scanning to one JPG.